# Java: Can not add data into SQLite DB

Tags: java

I try to add a new data into SQLite Database. The connection is established successfully, however, when I add new data, nothing is shown in the DB table. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you

```
package database;

import java.sql.*;

public class Database {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:admin.db");
        System.out.println("Connection is established");

        String SQLadd = "insert into" + "admins(user_name,password)" + "values('sachin', 'kafle')";
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(SQLadd);
        //c.commit();
        //c.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Can not connect to database");
        //System.exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You're missing a space between `into` and `admins` in your query `String`. Also, you shouldn't swallow the `Exception` like that (at least print the stack trace).

Comment: Are you getting any error?  The SQL statement might not be correct.  also check if you need to flush/close any connections/streams.

Comment: I dont get any error. I saw this code on a online course video so I just write the same  with the video's code. However, nothing's shown in DB table no matter my code have nothing different with the code in video

Comment: I did miss the space between "into" and "admins". Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give space between `into` and `admins`, also after `values`, or just do like following :

```
String SQLadd = "insert into admins(user_name,password) values('sachin', 'kafle')";
```

Hope it helps... :)